# Knockout ObservableArray.replace() function does not update 'optionsText' binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am attempting to refresh the state of an option entry in a select control by replacing the option in a knockout observable array. However, it appears that this does not work. Please see the following JSFiddle for an example of this.

http://jsfiddle.net/oneaj4z6/1/

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
   var item1 = {
      id: ko.observable(1),
      firstName: ko.observable('Tim'),
      lastName: ko.observable('Mit')
    };
   item1.optionsText = ko.computed(function() {
      return item1.firstName() + ' ' + item1.lastName();
    });
    item1.optionsValue = ko.computed(function() {
      return item1.id();
    });
    
    this.items = ko.observableArray([
     item1
    ]);
  
    this.onButton1Click = function (elem) {
      console.log("Clicked 1");
      item1.firstName(new Date().getTime());
    };
  
    this.onButton2Click = function (elem) {
      console.log("Clicked 2");

      var item1Replaced = {
        id: ko.observable(1),
        firstName: ko.observable('REPLACED'),
        lastName: ko.observable('YEAH!')
      };
      item1Replaced.optionsText = ko.computed(function() {
        return item1.firstName() + ' ' + item1.lastName();
      });
      item1Replaced.optionsValue = ko.computed(function() {
        return item1.id();
      });
      console.dir(item1);
      console.dir(item1Replaced);
      this.items.replace(item1, item1Replaced);
      
    };

    this.selectedItem = ko.observable(undefined);
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: items, value: selectedItem, optionsText: 'optionsText', optionsValue: 'optionsValue'"></select>
<br />
<button type="button" data-bind="click: onButton1Click">Modify Array Item</button>
<br />
<button type="button" data-bind="click: onButton2Click">Replace Array Item</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: This fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/oneaj4z6/4/) from @Sam.C resolves this issue.

It might just be an overlook but you are referring to the item1 instance in your computed definition (in your replace click handler definition), the code below should replace the select item.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
   var item1 = {
      id: ko.observable(1),
      firstName: ko.observable('Tim'),
      lastName: ko.observable('Mit')
    };
   item1.optionsText = ko.computed(function() {
      return item1.firstName() + ' ' + item1.lastName();
    });
    item1.optionsValue = ko.computed(function() {
      return item1.id();
    });
    
    this.items = ko.observableArray([
     item1
    ]);
  
    this.onButton1Click = function (elem) {
      console.log("Clicked 1");
      item1.firstName(new Date().getTime());
    };
  
    this.onButton2Click = function (elem) {
      console.log("Clicked 2");

      var item1Replaced = {
        id: ko.observable(1),
        firstName: ko.observable('REPLACED'),
        lastName: ko.observable('YEAH!')
      };
      item1Replaced.optionsText = ko.computed(function() {
        return item1Replaced.firstName() + ' ' + item1Replaced.lastName();
      });
      item1Replaced.optionsValue = ko.computed(function() {
        return item1Replaced.id();
      });
      console.dir(item1);
      console.dir(item1Replaced);
      this.items.replace(item1, item1Replaced);
      
    };

    this.selectedItem = ko.observable(undefined);
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: items, value: selectedItem, optionsText: 'optionsText', optionsValue: 'optionsValue'"></select>
<br />
<button type="button" data-bind="click: onButton1Click">Modify Array Item</button>
<br />
<button type="button" data-bind="click: onButton2Click">Replace Array Item</button>
```

Comment: I am not trying to replace the selected item. I am trying to replace any item in the array (which in this trivial example is item1).

Comment: the code is not trying to replace "the selected item" ... it's replacing the "item1" instance in the array with a new instance "item1Replaced" . It just happened that item1 was the "selectedItem". So the code in the answer is replacing the item in the array and the UI is reflecting it. The only reason your original code was not reflecting it is because the computed observable definition for "item1Replaced" was referring to "item1" fields ... apologies if I still don't fully understand your issue.

Comment: This is the correct answer and sshould be marked so.